# Rails, API endpoint that returns all Items for which the current_user is the seller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest

I need to set up an API end point that returns all the items for which the current_user is the seller. I'm doing my best to set up RESTful routes So for I have this:

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :users
    resources :items
    get "users/:id/items" => "users#items"
...
```

users_controller.rb

This returns all items where the seller_id column is equal to params[:id]. Eventually I'd like to add a buyer_id column to the items table and be able to filter for that as well - so I need to differentiate between buyer and seller. Obviously I am not doing that here.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def seller_items
        User.find(params[:id]).items
    end
end
```

item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :seller, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'seller_id'
    enum status: {available: 0, pending: 1, sold: 2, expired: 3, banned: 4 }
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :items, :class_name => 'Item', :foreign_key => 'seller_id'
end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160715043217) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "price",          limit: 8
    t.integer  "status"
    t.datetime "published_date"
    t.datetime "created_at",               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",               null: false
    t.integer  "seller_id"
  end

  add_index "items", ["seller_id"], name: "index_items_on_seller_id", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.decimal  "latitude",   precision: 9, scale: 6
    t.decimal  "longtitude", precision: 9, scale: 6
    t.datetime "created_at",                         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                         null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "items", "users", column: "seller_id"
end
```

Comment: You want _buyer_, and showing us _seller_ is not working. I am confused now :) What is the issue?

Comment: So, is there an actual question?

Comment: I think he's confused as to how to add in bought items based on what he's done for sold items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have separate controllers for each

routes.rb

```
get "users/:id/sold_items" => "sold_items#index"
get "users/:id/bought_items" => "bought_items#index"
```

Controllers

```
class SoldItemsController
  def index
    User.find(params[:id]).sold_items
  end
end

class BoughtItemsController
  def index
    User.find(params[:id]).bought_items
  end
end
```

models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sold_items, :class_name => 'Item', :foreign_key => 'seller_id'
  has_many :bought_items, :class_name => 'Item', :foreign_key => 'buyer_id'
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :seller, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'seller_id'
  belongs_to :buyer, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'buyer_id'
  enum status: {available: 0, pending: 1, sold: 2, expired: 3, banned: 4 }
end
```

Comment: great answer! Thanks.